# Хранилище картинок в Yii2

Tags: yii2, изображения, интернет-магазин, админка

есть такая задача:

Существует несколько поддоменов

```
crm.domain.net
shop1.domain.net
shop2.domain.net
```

Два интернет магазина на yii2 должны иметь общую админку в crm (тоже yii2)

Сделать админку с общей базой не проблема, но картинки товаров получается будут храниться в структуре папок поддомена crm и из shop1.domain.net shop2.domain.net я не знаю как их достать

Comment: Сохраните ваш домен `crm.domain.net` в параметрах системы и присваивайте изображениям аболютный путь к ним в сурсе. Как то так: `src="<?= \Yii->$app->params['imageSource'] . /img/abc.jpg ?>"`.

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше. Только дополню, что для ситуации когда часть картинок хранится на `crm`, а часть на `shopN` - Вам нужно будет для картинок из `crm` указывать полный путь к ним `https://crm.domain.net/images/...`, а для картинок `shopN` можно указывать относительный путь `/images`